# Is the below expression valid in NetSuite workflow?

Tags: netsuite

How should i write the expression to throw out weekend (Sat and Sun)?

`nlapiStringToChar(nlapiGetFieldValue('duedate'),'DY').valueOf()==nlapiStringToChar('SAT').valueOf()`

Answer (score 0):

I would run with something like this:

```
nlapiStringToDate(nlapiGetFieldValue('duedate')).toLocaleString('en-us',{weekday:'short'})=="Sat"
```

The first part will return the Short day name, and the second part would jsut be a string to compare it to.